# Problem with flex air application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

Good evening stackoverflow.. I am having problems with my flash builder 4 project
it is an air application and has a php service
Most of the time my app run fine but sometimes I recieve http errors and don't know how or why it happens. What I do is restart my app and it would run smoothly. One thing I noticed is that the busyCursor keeps on turning. It's like it loading something I think it is the calls that I make. I don't understand why sometimes it fails sometimes it works...could you help me clear this thing out??how can I avoid such errors?

Answer (score 0):

Install one of network monitors e.g. [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and find out what fails.